# Is there any difference between UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX and NONCLUSTERED INDEX?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and this index in my database was already created:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexT1 
ON T1 (
    [ID] ASC,
    [logID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([MasterID]) 
WHERE ([logID] IS NOT NULL)
```

I executed this query :

```
SELECT 
    R.X 
FROM
    R
LEFT JOIN 
    T1 ON T1.MasterID = R.MasterID
WHERE 
    T1.ID IS NULL 
    AND R.logID IS NULL
    AND T1.ItemID IN (SELECT MAX(R.ItemID)
                      FROM R
                      LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.MasterID = R.MasterID
                      WHERE T1.ID IS NULL 
                        AND R.logID IS NULL
                      GROUP BY R.MasterID)
```

And in the execution plan, SQL Server offer to me to create this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON T1 (
  [ID],
  [logID]
)
```

Does anybody know what is a difference between those indexes?

Because, I think the first ones cover the second ones! Why my query can not use the first ones?

Comment: I know that. But do you think because of Unique key word, SQL server is not capable to use this Index and it need another index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious difference that one enforces uniqueness, and the other one does not, there is another big difference.

Your first index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexT1 
ON T1 (
    [ID] ASC,
    [logID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [MasterID]) 
WHERE ([logID] IS NOT NULL) -- notice the WHERE clause here!
```

...is a [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) (notice the `where` clause).

On the other hand, your 2nd index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON T1 (
  [ID],
  [logID]
)
```

... is not.

What this means is that your filtered index does ***not*** include rows where `logID IS NULL`, and therefore, only enforces uniqueness of the `ID/logID` combination if `logID IS NOT NULL`.

The point here is that SQL Server is noticing that your query contains conditions on `logID IS NULL` that cannot benefit from the filtered index because the index doesn't include rows where `logID IS NULL`. So it naturally suggests a new index.